# Find if process is responding without using System.Diagnostics.Process.Responding

Tags: c#, windows-xp

**Good day everyone.**

This problem was part of [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506849/system-timers-timer-freezes-when-ui-thread-freezes-in-windows-xp) which it as been solved, i realized that what i thought it was the problem after all, it wasn't. Still thanks to that I've learned a couple things.

My application does loads of work with IE and from time to time, IE is redirected to a website with some bad Javascript code that ends up blocking IE interface. And consequently blocking my application too once everything on my application is running on the same `Thread`.

To counteract that problem, at startup my application runs a `static method` in another `Thread` that every 15 seconds does a simple check if IE is responding or not, and if IE isn't responding, he closes all its process's, liberating the lock on my application main `Thread` and then my application can resume its work.

To find if IE process's are responding i had a simple code like this:

```
bool terminate = false;
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process exe in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (exe.ProcessName.StartsWith("iexplore"))
    {
        if (exe.Responding == false)
        {
            terminate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
// Code to close all IE process's...
```

In order to the `Process.Responding` property finds if the process is responding, and according to information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding.aspx), this property needs another property named `MainWindowHandle` to be available in order to complete the process of checking. And if `MainWindowHandle` isn't available `Process.Responding` always returns true even if the process isn't responding.

And for some reason which i don't know. In Windows XP `MainWindowHandle` isn't available there so `Responding` isn't accurate.

Thats why i need to know another way to find if a specific process is responding or not in Windows XP.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**PS:** If your looking for a website to freeze IE here goes: http://aboutmycollege.com/

**EDIT: Following 0xA3 suggestion:**

I went through all IE process's checking if they had the `MainWindowHandle` property, those who had that property i send they `Responding` property to a MessageBox and they report correctly when IE isn't responding on Windows 7 but not on XP.

I executed this code every 15 seconds:

```
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process exe in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (exe.ProcessName.StartsWith("iexplore"))
            {
                if (exe.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Process doesn't have MainWindowHandle");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Process Responding: " + exe.Responding.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

In Windows 7 and Xp he reports the Process's of IE that don't have the `MainWindowHandle` property, and in Windows 7 he also reports correctly when IE isn't responding. But in XP all IE process's with `MainWindowHandle` are always responding even when they aren't.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: @ChickSentMeHighE: IE8. Beware that Process.Responding works well on Windows 7 but no XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE is special because each tab has its own process plus there is an additional parent IE process. In fact, only the parent process will have a valid `MainWindowHandle`.

Did you check whether `MainWindowHandle` is null for all these processes? If it isn't I think your code should work as expected on XP as well.

**Update**

Since checking all IE instances didn't help, the next thing I would try is to modify the timeout that is used by `Process.Responding`. The property internally calls the [`SendMessageTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644952%28VS.85%29.aspx) api function and then checks the return value whether a timeout occurred. If so, the process is assumed to be hanging. The timeout is a hard-coded value of 5 seconds.

You can call `SendMessageTimeout` yourself using P/Invoke and vary the timeout. Possibly a shorter value would give better results on Windows XP:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
    HandleRef hWnd, 
    int msg, 
    IntPtr wParam, 
    IntPtr lParam, 
    int flags, 
    int timeout, 
    out IntPtr pdwResult);

const int SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 2;

bool IsResponding(Process process)
{
    HandeRef handleRef = new HandleRef(process, process.MainWindowHandle);

    int timeout = 2000;
    IntPtr lpdwResult;

    IntPtr lResult = SendMessageTimeout(
        handleRef, 
        0, 
        IntPtr.Zero, 
        IntPtr.Zero, 
        SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 
        timeout, 
        out lpdwResult);

    return lResult != IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Comment: I didn't thought of that, my code only checks the first IE process and then reports back. Just a sec i will check them all.

Comment: My code stops checking if a Process.Responding reports false. Notice the break statement.

Comment: @Fábio Antunes: If `MainWindowHandle` isn't available `Process.Responding` always returns `true`, so the break statement would not be reached then.

Comment: My friend. THANKS. Worked pretty well, takes a few seconds longer in XP to recognize that IE as stopped responding but finally it did recognized. I used the code you provided and implemented in my Process handler class, and it works like a clock. I would love if you could explain to me what exactly you did.