# Determine if an application is blocked/busy?

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation

I'm trying to automate the GUI of an external application using C#/.NET 4.0

The application that's being automated (AUT) is a VB6 app.

When doing an action, or clicking a button, the AUT sometimes spends a lot of time waiting for the DB to respond. When the app is waiting for the DB results, the app itself is idle (doesn't register much CPU usage), but it's blocked (you can't click or interact with it).

-So far, I've tried looking at the mouse pointer (hourglass) as an indicator, but sometimes the app is blocked but cursor is normal. So this isn't reliable.

-I've tried looking at the main process of the AUT for TotalProcessorTime (this measures if the app is IDLE or BUSY), but like I said, sometimes the app is IDLE, and still blocked.

So i'd like to tape into the stackOverflow crowd's experience to see if anyone already knows how to handle that, and/or if you have any ideas on how to achieve this.

Thanks

EDIT:

I've been playing around, and just discovered something.

While the AUT is blocked, it isn't responding to keyboard or mouse input. However, if I send WM_LBUTTONCLICK messages to the window, I can confirm that the messages are being processed (and the UI changes).

So I'm guessing that they are purposefully blocking the app while making DB calls.

Comment: Is the UI disabled? Is the main UI thread blocking on a worker thread? Do you see Window ghosting if you attempt to interact with the app?

Comment: You can't interact with the main UI, however I don't think the main UI thread is blocking, as you don't see any "Ghosting" when you try to interact with it. It just doesn't do anything. And all the controls/UI are still "enabled".

Comment: Check with Spy++ whether or not the main window is disabled. If the message queue is being pumped, and you can't invoke UI actions, then something in AUT must be disabled I'd guess.

Comment: I just verified with Spy++, and whenever the application is blocked, in Spy++, the "Window Prod" is marked as "Unavailable". (and when it's not blocked, it displays the Proc's address)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether or not the UI of that application is responding:

Get the process instance for that application and check its `Responding` property. like:

```
//To get the process instance
Process  application = null;
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (process.ProcessName == "The Process Name")
    {
        application = process;
        break;
    }
}

//to check if the process UI is not responding
if (application.Responding)
{ 
    //
}
```

**Edit:** You can modify the timeout used by `application.Responding` check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514049/find-if-process-is-responding-without-using-system-diagnostics-process-responding/3514209#3514209).

Comment: I've just verified, and at a point where the application appears to be blocked, application.Responding returns TRUE, so we can't use that...

Comment: @DanyO: maybe your process doesn't have `MainWindowHandle`, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding.aspx) `If the process does not have a MainWindowHandle, this property returns true.`, otherwise this property should work "AFAIK", example: check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aykwfbdh(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I just verified, and the process does have a valid MainWindowHandle. From the documentation, doesn't "Process.Responding" apply only to applications that are considered hung? The application i'm testing isn't actually hung, it's just blocked until it receives a response from the database.

Comment: @DanyO: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514049/find-if-process-is-responding-without-using-system-diagnostics-process-responding/3514209#3514209).

Comment: just tried using the link you're suggesting, and it is still returning "TRUE" when the application is blocking. I even tried to lower the timeout to 1, and it's still returning TRUE.

Comment: @DanyO: I don't know how do you test when the application is blocking but here is an example: 
            `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((_) =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (!application.Responding)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not responding at {0}", DateTime.Now);
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }));`